Black bars appearingwhen moving image in CSS
I started using HTML/CSS, JS about a week ago and have ran into a slight problem. Im using the bootstrap carousel and its working great however when i try to move the image more to the top, i end up getting black bars on the bottom, its like something is automatically cropping my images.
When I adjust "bottom" to 50px, i get those black bars, but my intention is to just shift the image up. its a full image so i am 100% sure there is stuff below there. Anyone know whats going on?


  #img1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="overlay-image" id="img1" style="background-image:url(./images/madeira3.JPEG);"></div>
      <div class="container">






It seems that you have missed some amount of code in this question. Please, provide more information.

Please click [edit] then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add RELEVANT code to make a [mcve]

The problem you are encountering is because you are moving the element that displays the image up.
You have your image set as a background image, so you could use background attributes to position the image.
Doing something like this may help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
This will position the image centre both horizontally and vertically
#img1 {
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}

This will position the image horizontally centre and vertically top
#img1 {
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center top;
}

You can also add pixel values, say you want the top 50pixels always trimmed off,
#img1 {
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center -50px;
}


omg dude this is exactly what i needed, thank you so much

@Boriscodes you're welcome - if it fixed your problem please mark it as accepted answer :)

#img1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}




  #img1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="overlay-image" id="img1" style="background-image:url(./images/madeira3.JPEG);"></div>
      <div class="container">




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
